# Returning values from different cells in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to set up a formula in Excel where the program searches for a value in a column on a second sheet, and if it finds that value, it returns the value found on another column, same row as the found value.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible you can use Vlookup, Index Match just write an example of your Data

Comment: You can write a VBA. For Vlookup to work properly, your data should be in ascending order and there should be only one matching data as far as I know.

Comment: @berkus `VLOOKUP` works perfectly on non-sorted data, by setting parameter 4 to `False`.

Comment: @A.S.H: I see, true for multiple values?

Comment: @berkus in case of multiple matches it returns the first match (the top one).

Comment: @ASH: Is there a built-in solution for that or VBA is the way to go?

Comment: @berkus If you mean to return a list of all matches, well, there are formula solutions but VBA's solution is preferable.

Comment: Well, things that I do not like about VBA is the `.xlsm` extension that freaks people out and each time you need to pass a warning if the Excel is setup to do that way.. :(

Answer (score 0):

What you have described it a typical `VLOOKUP`, here is how you would go about implementing it.

`=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B17,2,TRUE)`

The first value is the cell that contains the value you want to search, this is followed by the range of your table, which you mentioned was in another sheet. Next you specify which column contains the value you want to return, in your case this will be 2. Lastly, this bit is optional, if you want the value search to be an exact match input `FALSE`, in a approximate match is good enough input `TRUE`

Note, the lookup range should include both columns; the columns you are going to search and the value you wish to return. Also in this range exclude the table titles if you have any.